# How do you create a bar plot for two variables mirrored across the x-axis in R?

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have a dataset with an x variable and two y1 and y2 variables (3 columns in total). I would like to plot y1 against x as a bar plot above the axis and y2 against the same x in the same plot underneath the x axis so that the two bar plots mirror each other.

Figure D below is an example of what I am trying to do.

[image: Figure **D**]

Comment: How did you made the graph A? I am very curious about the horse on the picture

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using `ggplot` you would go about it as follows:

Set up the data.  Nothing strange here, but clearly values below the axis will be negative.

```
dat <- data.frame(
    group = rep(c("Above", "Below"), each=10),
    x = rep(1:10, 2),
    y = c(runif(10, 0, 1), runif(10, -1, 0))
)
```

Plot using `ggplot` and `geom_bar`.  To prevent `geom_bar` from summarising the data, specify `stat="identity"`.  Similarly, stacking needs to be disabled by specifying `position="identity"`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Some very minimal examples for base graphics and `lattice` using @Andrie's example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    group = rep(c("Above", "Below"), each=10),
    x = rep(1:10, 2),
    y = c(runif(10, 0, 1), runif(10, -1, 0))
)
```

In base graphics:

```
plot(c(0,12),range(dat$y),type = "n")
barplot(height = dat$y[dat$group == 'Above'],add = TRUE,axes = FALSE)
barplot(height = dat$y[dat$group == 'Below'],add = TRUE,axes = FALSE)
```

[image: bar_base]

and in `lattice`:

```
barchart(y~x,data = dat, origin = 0, horizontal = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is done with ggplot2. 
First provide some data and put the two y together with melt.

```
library(ggplot2)

dtfrm <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y1 = rnorm(10, 50, 10), y2 = -rnorm(10, 50, 10))
dtfrm.molten <- melt(dtfrm, id = "x")
```

Then, make the graph

```
ggplot(dtfrm.molten, aes(x , value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity")
```

Perhpas someone else can provide an example with base and/or lattice.

HTH