# barplot with 3 variables (continuous X and Y and third stacked variable)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

I have some data like this:

```
myd <- structure(list(var1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("II", "III", 
       "IV", "V"), class = "factor"), zero_co = c(15.15152, 3.030303, 
        0, 0), non_zero_CO = c(84.84848, 96.969697, 100, 100), size = c(230, 
        813, 317, 1532)), .Names = c("var1", "zero_co", "non_zero_CO", 
        "size"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

# myd
# I                   II         III   IV     V  
# zero_co       15.15152    3.030303    0     0
# non-zero CO   84.84848   96.969697  100   100
# size         230.00000  813.000000  317  1532
```

I want to plot `size` on the y-axis and other two variables `zero_co` and `non-zero CO` as a stacked bars on the x-axis. I am trying to plot this using `gplots` and `ggplots` but finding difficulties. How do I plot this?

Comment: your data is absolutely unreadable. Learn how to make reproducible example in R: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/684229

Comment: sorry for that.. I have edited it now.

Comment: Can you show what you did ?

Comment: basically I tried following this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999144/how-do-you-create-a-bar-plot-for-two-variables-mirrored-across-the-x-axis-in-r

Comment: I mean what is your own code (adopted from the post) and error message if you got any !

Comment: I am not any expert in R, and from that post I tried changing variables and column names but its giving error as invalid subscript type. Please  be nice am still a beginner.

Comment: Don't worry, I think your question is perfectly valid and brushed up the markup a bit to make it easier to read. It would indeed help though if you added your own code so that we have something to start working from.

Comment: thank you Backlin. But I really tried to plot it on my own and finally posted it here.

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out how you want the final plot to look though. A barplot can only show one variable or groupings per axis. I take it that you want `size` te be plotted on `y` but fail to see how `zero_co` and `non-zero_CO` fit in. They appear to be continuous variables rather than groupings. So to clarify please provide either your non-working code or a mock-up picture of what you want to create.

Comment: Hi backlin - here is what actually what I want to do. as you said zero_co and non-zero_co doesn't fit in. what I wanted to show is, how zero_co and non-zero_co are related to length (of chromosome) variable. So I thought if put two variables as a stacked bar and show length on y-axis, it would clear it up. But it was a dumb idea . Is there any better way to achieve this ?? And I counldn't find no mock-up picture, sorry.

Comment: @poisonAlien I do not intend not to be nice, getting help is much faster if you can provide whatever you are trying, I am not expert either ... otherwise people have hardtime to understand what is the problem and what you intend to do ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution if I understand it correctly. As you have quantative variable at both x and y axis you can not do with bar plot. You need to use rectangle (look like bar anyway).

```
myd <- data.frame (var1 = c("II", "III", "IV", "V"), zero_co = c(15.15152 , 3.030303,    0,     0),
             non_zero_CO = c(84.84848,   96.969697,  100,   100),
              size = c(230.00000,  813.000000,  317,  1532))

    require(ggplot2)

ggplot(myd) + geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = zero_co, ymin =size , ymax =size + 80 ), fill = "lightgreen") +
geom_rect(aes(xmin = zero_co, xmax = zero_co + non_zero_CO, ymin =size , ymax =size + 80 ), fill = "darkblue") + theme_bw()
```

Give you the plot:

[image]

Comment: @poison Alien Can you confirm if this is what you are looking for ?

Comment: Hi jon - Thank you vary much for the answers. This is what  I was looking for !

Answer (score 3):

Here is where I could get to based on my limited understanding:

```
myd <- data.frame (var1 = c("II", "III", "IV", "V"), zero_co = c(15.15152 , 3.030303,    0,     0),
             non_zero_CO = c(84.84848,   96.969697,  100,   100),
              size = c(230.00000,  813.000000,  317,  1532))
myd1 <- as.matrix (t(myd[,2:3]))

barplot(myd1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you wish the final plot to look like but here's a `ggplot2` proposal.

First, reshape the data into the long format:

```
library(reshape2)
myd_long <- melt(myd, measure.vars = c("zero_co", "non_zero_CO"))
```

Calculate absolute value (I suppose `value` represents the percentage of `size`.):

```
myd_long <- within(myd_long, valueAbs <- size * value / 100)
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)    

ggplot(myd_long, aes(y = valueAbs, x = var1, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]