# Two sided bar plot ordered by date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a double-sided bar plot like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6999487/1191125), but I want to order bars by date and change the x-axis labels to other values (not dates). My data set looks like:

```
         date          rival goals misses
1  2015-07-19         Динамо     2      1
2  2015-07-26           Урал     4      1
3  2015-08-01          Терек     3      0
4  2015-08-09            Уфа     1      0
5  2015-08-15      Краснодар     0      2
6  2015-08-24          Рубин     3      1
7  2015-08-29 Крылья Советов     1      3
8  2015-09-12           ЦСКА     2      2
9  2015-09-20          Амкар     1      1
10 2015-09-26        Спартак     2      2
11 2015-10-03         Ростов     3      0
12 2015-10-17         Кубань     2      2
13 2015-10-24           Анжи     5      1
14 2015-10-31       Мордовия     0      0
15 2015-11-08      Локомотив     0      2
16 2015-11-21           Урал     3      0
17 2015-11-28          Терек     1      4
18 2015-12-03            Уфа     1      1
```

You can download it by this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybhi8wnp81hwkln/2015-2016.csv?dl=1). I use next code to make chart:

```
x = read.csv("data/2015-2016.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
x$date = as.Date(x$date, "%d.%m.%Y")

goalsToMisses = data.frame(
  group = c(rep("Goals", nrow(x)), rep("Misses", nrow(x))),
  date = rep(x$date, 2),
  x = rep(x$rival, 2),
  y = c(x$goals, - x$misses),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

ggplot(goalsToMisses, aes(x = reorder(x, date), y = y, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity") +
  ylim(- max(x$goals), max(x$goals)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(- max(x$goals), max(x$goals), 1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 15))
```

And I get this:
[image]

But the ordering is wrong; it should be as in initial data set, from top to bottom. How I can fix it?

**Update:** The main difference from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/how-to-change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale-in-ggplot) is that I use a two-sided bar plot and `goalsToMisses` data frame twice more than the initial data frame.

Also, I can't set levels on `rival` factor because `rival` column contains duplicates and I got `duplicated levels in factors are deprecated` error.

Comment: just set the order of your factor (rival) levels

Comment: using goalsToMisses$rival <- factor(goalsToMisses$rival, levels = c("Динамо", "Урал"...... "Уфа"))

Comment: And specify whatever labels you want either as the names of the factor levels or `scale_x_discrete(labels = c("label1", "custom label 2", ....))

Comment: Guys, thank you for responses, but no one doesn't help me. Please see update in the bottom of the post.

Comment: Do you really want to plot the dates on the x axis and just put the name of the rival team as tick labels instead of the actual date?  If not, what do you want to do with the rival team that was played twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should to add tricky factor with right levels ordering:

```
x = read.csv("data/2015-2016.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
x$date = as.Date(x$date, "%d.%m.%Y")

goalsToMisses = data.frame(
  group = c(rep("Goals", nrow(x)), rep("Misses", nrow(x))),
  x = paste(rep(x$rival, 2), "\n(", rep(x$date, 2), ")", sep=""),
  y = c(x$goals, - x$misses),
  stringsAsFactors = F)

matches = unique(goalsToMisses$x)
goalsToMisses$x = factor(goalsToMisses$x, levels = matches[order(x$date)])

ggplot(goalsToMisses, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity") +
  ylim(- max(x$goals), max(x$goals)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(- max(x$goals), max(x$goals), 1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 15))
```

[image]

Comment: I agree that it's appropriate to keep the dates on the graphic.  You could also have solved the problem by using `date`, a factor with levels in the order of the dataset, as the x axis variable and simply replacing the tick labels with `x$rival` in `scale_x_discrete`.