# Twosided Barplot in R with different data

Tags: r, bar-chart

I was wondering if it's possible to get a two sided barplot (e.g. [Two sided bar plot ordered by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140476/two-sided-bar-plot-ordered-by-date)) that shows above **Data A** and below **Data B** of each X-Value.

**Data A** would be for example the age of a person and **Data B** the size of the same person. The problem with this and the main difference to the examples above: A and B have obviously totally different units/ylims.

**Example:**

```
X = c("Anna","Manuel","Laura","Jeanne") # Name of the Person
A = c(12,18,22,10)     # Age in years
B = c(112,186,165,120) # Size in cm
```

Any ideas how to solve this? I don't mind a horizontal or a vertical solution.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's code that gets you a solid draft of what I think you want using `barplot` from base R. I'm just making one series negative for the plotting, then manually setting the labels in `axis` to reference the original (positive) values. You have to make a choice about how to scale the two series so the comparison is still informative. I did that here by dividing height in cm by 10, which produces a range similar to the range for years.

```
# plot the first series, but manually set the range of the y-axis to set up the
# plotting of the other series. Set axes = FALSE so you can get the y-axis
# with labels you want in a later step.
barplot(A, ylim = c(-25, 25), axes = FALSE)

# plot the second series, making whatever transformations you need as you go. Use
# add = TRUE to add it to the first plot; use names.arg to get X as labels; and
# repeat axes = FALSE so you don't get an axis here, either.
barplot(-B/10, add = TRUE, names.arg = X, axes = FALSE)

# add a line for the x-axis if you want one
abline(h = 0)

# now add a y-axis with labels that makes sense. I set lwd = 0 so you just
# get the labels, no line.
axis(2, lwd = 0, tick = FALSE, at = seq(-20,20,5),
     labels = c(rev(seq(0,200,50)), seq(5,20,5)), las = 2)

# now add y-axis labels
mtext("age (years)", 2, line = 3, at = 12.5)
mtext("height (cm)", 2, line = 3, at = -12.5)
```

Result with `par(mai = c(0.5, 1, 0.25, 0.25))`:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted! Thanks! :-)