# Two vertical bar charts with shared x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r

[I would like to make graphs similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4hcS.png)

How can I make graphs like this using R?

I have read [Two horizontal bar charts with shared axis in ggplot2 (similar to population pyramid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265941/two-horizontal-bar-charts-with-shared-axis-in-ggplot2-similar-to-population-pyr)
and he can make [horizontial bar charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00nPi.png) using the following R code:

```
  g.mid<-ggplot(tp07,aes(x=1,y=sch))+geom_text(aes(label=sch))+
geom_segment(aes(x=0.94,xend=0.96,yend=sch))+
geom_segment(aes(x=1.04,xend=1.065,yend=sch))+
ggtitle("")+
   ylab(NULL)+
   scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0.94,1.065))+
   theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
         panel.grid=element_blank(),
         axis.text.y=element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
       panel.background=element_blank(),
         axis.text.x=element_text(color=NA),
         axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=NA),
         plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,-1), "mm"))
 g1 <- ggplot(data = tp07, aes(x = sch, y = ans0)) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Number of student never or Seldom have breakfast") +
 theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
         axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
         axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
         axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
         plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,0), "mm")) +
   scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip()
 g2 <- ggplot(data = tp07, aes(x = sch, y = ans7)) +xlab(NULL)+
geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("No. of students have breakfsat 7 days a week") +
 theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
         axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
         plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,-1), "mm")) +
 coord_flip()

library(gridExtra)
gg1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
gg2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2))
gg.mid <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g.mid))

grid.arrange(gg1,gg.mid,gg2,ncol=3,widths=c(4/9,1/9,4/9))
```

how can I change it from horizontal to vertical?
And I would like to keep the x-axis in the middle part of the graph that separate the two variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a bar plot for two variables mirrored across the x-axis in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999144/how-do-you-create-a-bar-plot-for-two-variables-mirrored-across-the-x-axis-in-r)

Comment: Try adding `position="identity"`

Comment: Remove `coord_flip()` from both plots

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian where should I add it?

Comment: @thepule it didn't work

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian but I how can I make the x-axis in the middle of the graph instead of placing it in the bottom

Comment: Try adding it along with `stat = "identity"`, inside `geom_bar()`

Comment: Can you add an example of the data frame you are using, so we can test the code?

Comment: @alexms im not sure what you mean by that comment, in the link i posted the x axis is in the middle...don't look at the question plots look at the plots posted in the answer...

Comment: @thepule I am sorry, below is the example
sch<-c("sch_a","sch_b","sch_c","sch_d","sch_d")
ans0<-c(2,4,7,8,2)
ans7<-c(4,13,4,6,0)
sch<-c("sch_a","sch_b","sch_c","sch_d","sch_d")
tp07<-data.frame(cbind(sch,ans0,ans7))

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian I meant place all the x-axis labels in the middle part of the graph,separating the two vertical bar chart.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian It didn't work too:(.

Comment: There is some error in `g1` you have to rectify that first. `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(x) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tp07` is the following:

```
tp07 <- structure(list(sch = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("sch_a", 
"sch_b", "sch_c", "sch_d"), class = "factor"), ans0 = c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 1), ans7 = c(3, 2, 3, 4, 1)), .Names = c("sch", "ans0", 
"ans7"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code below does the job:

```
g.mid_ <- ggplot(tp07,aes(x=sch,y=1))+geom_text(aes(label=sch))+
    geom_segment(aes(y=0.94,yend=0.96,xend=sch))+
    geom_segment(aes(y=1.04,yend=1.065,xend=sch))+
    ggtitle("") +
    xlab(NULL) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0.94,1.065))+
    theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
          panel.grid=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          panel.background=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_text(color=NA),
          axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=NA),
          plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,-1), "mm"))


g1_ <- ggplot(data = tp07, aes(x = sch, y = ans0)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
          plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,0), "mm")) +
    scale_y_reverse()


g2_ <- ggplot(data = tp07, aes(x = sch, y = ans7)) +xlab(NULL)+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
          axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,-1), "mm")) 


gg1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1_))
gg2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2_))
gg.mid <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g.mid_))

grid.arrange(gg2, gg.mid,gg1,nrow=3, heights=c(4/10,2/10,4/10))
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you!this is the graph that I want.

Comment: But it there any ways to make the labels in the middle part of the bar?
As when it comes to having more than 100 rows of data, the labels are not  under/on the right bar. And can i display the labels in vertical instead of horizontal? Thanks you!

Comment: The problem is solved using the following code, thanks a lot for your help!