# How to create two sided chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a two-sided chart where the "target" variable is on the x axe,"birds" and "wolfs" are on the left-hand side of the y axe, each with its own proportions.

```
df<- read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     
                              1     0.3      0.5 
                              0     0.9      0.2  ",header = TRUE)
```

I tried to follow the code in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999144/how-do-you-create-a-bar-plot-for-two-variables-mirrored-across-the-x-axis-in-r/6999487#6999487) to suit my goal but with no success. How can I overcome this problem?

Update: attached is a sketch
[image]

Comment: the link is not shown and can you give an example figure?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have target on x axis which defines basically left and right, but also birds and wolf show left an right?

Comment: Hello,@drmariod, link Attached. The idea is to show the success rate (values) of each variable in respect to the target 0/1

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what the two sides are, and how that would work with target being on the x-axis. Perhaps a little sketch would help us along.

Comment: I believe that this is _intentionally_ not possible.  See Hadley's  comments at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/4752675

Comment: Hello @Axeman, I added a sketch.Hope it is clear now.

Comment: _""birds" are on the left-hand side and "wolfs" is on the right-hand side"_, that's where the confusion came, since that is not what is in your picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df<- read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     
                              1     0.3      0.5 
                              0     0.9      0.2  ",header = TRUE)

df[df$target==0,] <- -df[df$target==0,]
df <- tidyr::gather(df,animal,value,c(birds,wolfs))

ggplot(df, aes(x = animal, y = value, fill = target)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   coord_flip()
```

Try the above?

Comment: You'll want `target` as a factor though. And you can use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a little reshaping for that, and `ifelse` to be a bit on the lazy side:

```
df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, 'var', 'val', -target)
ggplot(df2, aes(var)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = ifelse(target == 0, -val, val), fill = factor(target))) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Axeman, I'm not sure I understand how to use it with my data, How can I use my data in your code, I don't see a placeholder for the "birds" and "wolfs"?

Comment: @mql4beginner: Oops, I omitted a line of code, sorry.