# Histogram to decide whether two distributions have the same shape in R

Tags: r, histogram, dummy-variable, t-test

I would like to create a diagram in R as shown below (right) where i can show the distribution of my dummy variable, reservation (1) or walk-in (0), as separate.

This in order to do a correct analysis of the Mann-Whitney U test.

I want to make the right diagram

[image: I want to make the right diagram]

Who knows how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541713/how-to-plot-two-histograms-together-in-r?rq=1

Comment: You should at least try something first. Then ask for help.

Comment: Maybe plot on both sides of xaxis? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999144/how-do-you-create-a-bar-plot-for-two-variables-mirrored-across-the-x-axis-in-r) for an example.

Comment: @rawr linked post doesn't solve the problem, when 2 histograms are in complete overlap.