# stack bar plot with positive values above x axis and negative values below x axis

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want a mirror bar plot showing postive vales above x axis and negative values below x axis. but i got a graph like this.

[image]

```
library(plotly)
Region <- c("Cerebellum","Cortex","Hippocampus", "Striatum")
Positive <- c(sum(DataToPlot_Mouse_REJ$Cb_MicREJ > 0),sum(DataToPlot_Mouse_REJ$Ctx_MicREJ > 0),sum(DataToPlot_Mouse_REJ$Hipc_MicREJ > 0),sum(DataToPlot_Mouse_REJ$Str_MicREJ > 0) )

Negative <- c(sum(DataToPlot_Mouse_REJ$Cb_MicREJ < 0),sum(DataToPlot_Mouse_REJ$Ctx_MicREJ < 0),sum(DataToPlot_Mouse_REJ$Hipc_MicREJ < 0),sum(DataToPlot_Mouse_REJ$Str_MicREJ < 0) )


df <- data.frame(Region,Positive,Negative )
plot_ly(df) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~Region, y = ~Positive, type = 'bar', name = 'UpRegulated',
              marker = list(color = '#33adff'),
              hovertemplate = paste('Positive: %{y}',
                                    '
Region: %{x}
')) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~Region, y = ~Negative, type = 'bar', name = 'DownRegulated',
              marker = list(color = '#ff6666'),
              hovertemplate = paste('Negative: %{y}',
                                    '
Region: %{x}
'))
```

I tried above code and got bar plot showing both positive and negative values above x axis. i want negative values below the x axis like mirror image.

This is the dataframe. I am trying it in R studio.

| Region | Positive | negative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cerebellum | 550 | 115 |
| Cortex | 90 | 97 |
| Hippcampus | 170 | 128 |
| Striatum | 417 | 39 |

Comment: Column negative is required to keep as negative value, so that mirror image will form.To stack both negative and positive bars together, the layout(barmode = 'relative', yaxis = list(title = 'Values')) is used. This ensures that the bars are stacked relative to each other., as u can find in answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep negative for Negative values in the dataframe. aswell as Additionally, layout(barmode = 'relative') is required if  positive and negative bars needed to stack relative to each other.

```
library(plotly)

Region <- c("Cerebellum", "Cortex", "Hippocampus", "Striatum")
Positive <- c(550, 90, 170, 417)
Negative <- c(-115, -97, -128, -39)

df <- data.frame(Region, Positive, Negative)

plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Region, y = ~Positive, type = 'bar', name = 'UpRegulated',
            marker = list(color = '#33adff'),
            hovertemplate = paste('Positive: %{y}',
                                  '
Region: %{x}
')) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Region, y = ~Negative, type = 'bar', name = 'DownRegulated',
            marker = list(color = '#ff6666'),
            hovertemplate = paste('Negative: %{y}',
                                  '
Region: %{x}
')) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'relative', yaxis = list(title = 'Values'))
```

Comment: Thanks . this worked for me. But there is one more thing. As number of down regulated genes should not appear on graph as negative values. I just want to show number of up and downregulated genes as mirror image keeping the number on y axis positive. Is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please find new code below, I wrote, despite editing above code, so u can track changes and able to understand where changes I made

Comment: If u like ggplot, to acheive same , u can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770883/how-to-create-bi-directional-or-mirror-bar-plot-for-multiple-variables-using-r
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999144/how-do-you-create-a-bar-plot-for-two-variables-mirrored-across-the-x-axis-in-r

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, that you want to display the negative y-axis labels as positive values without changing the data, you can achieve this by customizing the tick labels on the y-axis. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
library(plotly)

Region <- c("Cerebellum", "Cortex", "Hippocampus", "Striatum")
Positive <- c(550, 90, 170, 417)
Negative <- c(-115, -97, -128, -39)

df <- data.frame(Region, Positive, Negative)

plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Region, y = ~Positive, type = 'bar', name = 'UpRegulated',
            marker = list(color = '#33adff'),
            hovertemplate = paste('Positive: %{y}',
                                  '
Region: %{x}
')) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Region, y = ~Negative, type = 'bar', name = 'DownRegulated',
            marker = list(color = '#ff6666'),
            hovertemplate = paste('Negative: %{y}',
                                  '
Region: %{x}
')) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'relative', yaxis = list(title = 'Values', tickvals = c(-100, 0, 100, 200,300,400,500),
                                            ticktext = c(100, 0, 100, 200,300,400,500)))# I have customised it as u can see negative value i replaced with positive value for example -100 to 100
```

[image]

I hope this answer your question, Also I am not good at english so sometime i amy misinterpreet, if i am right please let me know

Comment: Thank you so much. You got my point and now it is done as i was trying to do. I Really appreciate your efforts.